# Any documentary films on Sound Design in Film?

Tags: sound-effects, film-sound-design, documentary

I've a bit of free time at the moment so I've been watching some films and documentaries. I've watched some docs on the topics of film v digital (side by side) and other docs on video special effects. I'm just wondering if there are any good documentaries on the advances or progression of sound design in film?

I've watched a number of the videos on Sound Works Collection but these are just on about individual films.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a good read about robocop and how the sounds evolved with the characters: [http://hollywoodlostandfound.net/sound/robocop/](http://hollywoodlostandfound.net/sound/robocop/)

Answer (score 3):

The link here is not specifically about sound design in film but about how sounds get patented and are linked to certain products. I found it very interesting as to how a sound can remind us of something or make us do or buy something. I thought you might enjoy it. A neurological sonic trip.

http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/the-sizzle/

Answer (score 0):

There is another episode of 99% invisible that is about sound design in live sports.  It is really worthwhile:

http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/the-sound-of-sports/

Answer (score -1):

It's not out yet, but there is an excellent one currently in post-production (my daughter is an assistant editor on the project).

[Making Waves: The Art of Cinematic Sound](http://www.makingwavesmovie.com/)